# How computer driven ignition timing on gas engines work?

Tags: c++

I have been dabbling with writing a C++ program that would control spark timing on a gas engine and have been running in to some trouble.  My code is very simple.  It starts by creating a second thread that works to emulate the output signal of a Hall Effect sensor that is triggered once per engine revolution.  My main code processes the fake sensor output, recalculates engine rpm, and then determines the time necessary to wait for the crankshaft to rotate to the correct angle to send spark to the engine.  The problem I'm running into is that I am using a sleep function in milliseconds and at higher RPM's I am losing a significant amount of data.

My question is how are real automotive ECU's programed to be able to control spark at high RPM's accurately?

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "GetTimeMs64.cpp"

using namespace std;

void HEEmulator(void * );

int HE_Sensor1;

int *sensor;

HANDLE handles[1];

bool run;
bool *areRun;

int main( void )
{
    int sentRpm = 4000;

    areRun = &run;

    sensor = &HE_Sensor1;

    *sensor = 1;

    run = TRUE;

    int rpm, advance, dwell, oHE_Sensor1, spark;

    oHE_Sensor1 = 1;

    advance = 20;

    uint64 rtime1, rtime2, intTime, curTime, sparkon, sparkoff;

    handles[0] = (HANDLE)_beginthread(HEEmulator, 0, &sentRpm);

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("output.out");

    intTime = GetTimeMs64();
    rtime1 = intTime;
    rpm = 0;
    spark = 0;
    dwell = 10000;
    sparkoff = 0;

    while(run == TRUE)
    {
        rtime2 = GetTimeMs64();
        curTime = rtime2-intTime;
        myfile << "Current Time = " << curTime << "    ";
        myfile << "HE_Sensor1 = " << HE_Sensor1 << "    ";
        myfile << "RPM = " << rpm << "    ";
        myfile << "Spark = " << spark << "    ";

        if(oHE_Sensor1 != HE_Sensor1)
        {
            if(HE_Sensor1 > 0)
            {
                rpm = (1/(double)(rtime2-rtime1))*60000;
                dwell = (1-((double)advance/360))*(rtime2-rtime1);
                rtime1 = rtime2;
            }
                oHE_Sensor1 = HE_Sensor1;
        }

        if(rtime2 >= (rtime1 + dwell))
        {
            spark = 1;
            sparkoff = rtime2 + 2;
        }

        if(rtime2 >= sparkoff)
        {
            spark = 0;
        }

        myfile << "\n";

        Sleep(1);
    }

    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}

void HEEmulator(void *arg)
{
    int *rpmAd = (int*)arg;

    int rpm = *rpmAd;

    int milliseconds = (1/(double)rpm)*60000;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        *sensor = 1;
        Sleep(milliseconds * 0.2);
        *sensor = 0;
        Sleep(milliseconds * 0.8);
    }

    *areRun = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: `real automotive ECU's` are not programmed on Windows. I'd suggest reading some resources on embedded systems, your question is too broad to be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A desktop PC is not a real-time processing system.

When you use `Sleep` to pause a thread, you don't have any guarantees that it will wake up exactly after the specified amount of time has elapsed. The thread will be marked as ready to resume execution, but it may still have to wait for the OS to actually schedule it. From the documentation of the [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

> Note that a ready thread is not guaranteed to run immediately. Consequently, the thread may not run until some time after the sleep interval elapses.

Also, the resolution of the system clock ticks is limited.

To more accurately simulate an ECU and the attached sensors, you should not use threads. Your simulation should not even depend on the passage of real time. Instead, use a single loop that updates the state of your simulation (both ECU and sensors) with each tick. This also means that your simulation should include the clock of the ECU.

Comment: So from what I gather, the best I can do on a desktop PC is use the clock() function to get the number of ticks that pass.  My desktop seems to be running at 1 tick per millisecond.  Is my understanding correct that in order to run any faster (to gather more precision)  I would have to be running on different hardware?

Comment: @Icarus: the rate at which your real system clock ticks should not matter. Again, your simulation should not depend on the passage of real time. Use simulated time: one loop iteration represents whatever amount of simulated time that you want it to represent, e.g. 1 microsecond.